# Ng2-smart-table : Use datepicker format in the field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, ng2-smart-table

Is there any probability that I can use datepicker format in the ng2-smart-table.

```
jobSettings2: object = {
    columns: [
      {
        displayName: "Job ID",
        valueAs: "JobID",
        align: "left",
        columnWidth: "",
        type: "text",
        required: true
      },  



   <ng2-smart-table id="tableID" class="table table-hover" [settings]="jobSettings" [source]="jobSource" (userRowSelect)="selectjobs($event)"></ng2-smart-table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data you can use `npm install --save ng-pick-datetime` , This provide many features to play with date.

If you want to use date picker with `ng2-smart-table` , you can do by it's property named **renderComponent**.

```
{
 columns: {
    startDate: {
    title: 'Start Time',
    type: 'custom',
    renderComponent: SmartTableDatepickerRenderComponent,
    width: '250px',
    filter: false,
    sortDirection: 'desc',
    editor: {
      type: 'custom',
      component: SmartTableDatepickerComponent,
    }
  },
  endDate: {
    title: 'End Time',
    type: 'custom',
    renderComponent: SmartTableDatepickerRenderComponent,
    width: '250px',
    filter: false,
    editor: {
      type: 'custom',
      component: SmartTableDatepickerComponent,
      config: {
        placeholder: 'End Time'
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Hear you have to manage by another component. And you have to render that component into `ng2-smart-table`.

For more information please check this [link.](https://gist.github.com/brgaulin/d49a3d0883fd60d1c1ab14210210482c)